# How to plot a time series with ordinal levels in Plotly Python

Tags: plotly-python

I have time series data recorded at discrete ordinal levels (e.g. `0`, `1`, `2`), and I'd like to plot them with meaningful names (e.g. `low`, `medium`, `high`).

Currently I have:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04"],
    "y": [2, 1, 2, 0],
})

fig = px.line(x=df.x, y=df.y, line_shape="hv")
fig.show()
```

which produces:

[image: Plot showing a continuous y axis and time series x axis]

But I'd like something like:

[image: The same data, but showing an ordinal y axis and time series x axis]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like the easiest way:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04"],
    "y": [2, 1, 2, 0],
})

fig = px.line(x=df.x, y=df.y, line_shape="hv")
fig.update_yaxes(
    ticktext=["Low", "Medium", "High"],
    tickvals=[0, 1, 2],
)

fig.show()
```

Result:

[image: Graph showing the high, medium, low labels on the y axis]

---

In Plotly language this falls under the "categorical" umbrella.

If the order needs tweaked, the `categoryarray` and `categoryorder` can also be set with `update_yaxes`.

- https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-categoryarray
- https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-categoryorder